# Facebook API - User object returning strange values

Tags: facebook, api, object, properties

I have a [user object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user), but it's only properties  are `education, first_name, id, last_name, link, locale, location, name, timezone, updated_time, verified`. Not only is this missing properties that should be public (like `picture`), but also these values are different from the documentation (`updated_time` vs `last_updated`). Finally, strangely, I get the same thing from the link on the documentation page ([here](https://graph.facebook.com/me)). Ultimately, I'm trying to get `user.feed`.

Any ideas about what's going on will be greatly appreciated. Am I missing something obvious?

**visiting https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed gives the following:**

> {    "error": {
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "message": "An active access token must be used to query
>   information about the current user."
>   } }

**Why do I need an active access token? [the docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user) say that `picture` and `feed` are public!**

Here is the code. The `user` object is logged to Firebug.console:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function update_user_box() {
var user_box = document.getElementById("user");
FB.api('/me', function(user) { 
user_box.innerHTML = "<fb:profile-pic uid=\"loggedinuser\" useyou=\"false\"></fb:profile-pic>"
+ "Hey " + user.first_name + "<br>";
FB.XFBML.parse();
console.log(user);
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div id='user'><fb:login-button onlogin="update_user_box();"></fb:login-button></div>
<br><br>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
FB.init({
appId  : 'b07e858317c9069d450023b7500b4511',
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.session) {
update_user_box();
} else {
// no user session available, someone you dont know
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try get with username or id `https://graph.facebook.com/{ID @ username}/feed/`

Comment: you need access_token every-time you want to ask API to provide data as JSON object. I think you're correct about public feed. Can you try something like this manually https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}

Comment: @haha yes that works. 

https://graph.facebook.com/ID_OR_USER_NAME/feed

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that you can try

- check if the data is matching correctly with https://graph.facebook.com/{YOUR_FB_ID}
- Is there any data (that are null) needs extended permission. See [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions)
- Are you using right auth_token and oAuth2.0

I hope these will help you debugging.

---

Edit:

We faced a problem where we were using old API (FB-connect) and trying to get data mentioned in extended permission. We were not able to -- for some reason. We switched to oAuth2.0, and it worked. #3 bullet was just to share my experience.

Also, for photos we just fetched data from http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/picture

Comment: thank you for you suggestions! if you reread my post you'll find that I linked to the graph.facebook.com and it does match. there are no null values. i'm not sure how your last point could effect this.

Comment: The third point was just to make sure that you are using new API. I have seen problem with Extended permission when I used FB-Connect API. For profile image, we fetched the data simply by creating http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/picture

Comment: I see. I've included the code now. I am using the new API.....PS. aha! that link has helped me fin me some new information! I'm going to update my OP again right away.

Answer (score 0):

Get [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) from user for offline_access.

Feed `https://graph.facebook.com/{ID@username}/feed/`

Comment: err, maybe i dont understand, but this is on a webpage, and `user.feed` is listed as "Publicly available" for public posts same as `first_name` which works and `user.picture` which is mysteriously absent. this also does not explain the name difference for `the last_update` time.

Comment: well, as per FB doc, under http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions read_stream -- it says, "Provides access to all the posts in the user's News Feed and enables your application to perform searches against the user's News Feed"

Comment: yes, but that is for `user.home`, the news feed. i want the user's wall posts, which are in `user.feed`, which only "Requires the read_stream permission to see non-public posts"

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user